# DOCKER Oracle Database setup was not successful on Mac OS X

Tags: oracle, macos, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to compose an oracle 12.1.0.2 instance on my mac and see below error. I have allocated 10GB as memory. Can you help me with this issue. Google search tells me that similar issues were resolved by adding memory which I increased from 2GB to 10GB.  The issue still persists.

Below is the snapshot of error.

```
docker run <Project>/oracle-12.1                                                                                                                                      
[9:46:39]
ORACLE PASSWORD FOR SYS, SYSTEM AND PDBADMIN: <<PWD>>

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 26-OCT-2017 
04:17:09

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/3e22fe616ced/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                26-OCT-2017 04:17:09
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/3e22fe616ced/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
Copying database files
1% complete
2% complete
27% complete
Creating and starting Oracle instance
29% complete
32% complete
33% complete
34% complete
38% complete
42% complete
DBCA Operation failed.
Look at the log file "/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/ORCLCDB/ORCLCDB.log" for further details.
Unique database identifier check passed.

/opt/oracle/oradata/ has enough space. Required space is 7665 MB , available space is 48913 MB.
/ has enough space. Required space is 0 MB , available space is 48913 MB.
File Validations Successful.
Copying database files
DBCA_PROGRESS : 1%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 2%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 27%
Creating and starting Oracle instance
DBCA_PROGRESS : 29%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 32%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 33%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 34%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 38%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 42%
Error while executing "/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/dbmssml.sql". Refer to "/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/ORCLCDB/dbmssml0.log" for more details. Error in Process: /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/perl/bin/perl
DBCA_PROGRESS : DBCA Operation failed.
```

Comment: What does the log says ?

Comment: The log file is empty. Looks like its problem with the perl version on the oracle 12.1.0.2 image in docker. Was able to workaround using the steps mentioned here..https://laurent-leturgez.com/2015/05/26/oracle-12c-vmware-fusion-and-the-perl-binarys-segmentation-fault/